# throw new Error(`Could not find path "${filterPath}" in schema`);

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my schema of mongo collection

```
const intakeFoodSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email:{
      type:String,
      required:true,
      unique:true,
  },
  dateNo:{
          type:Array,
          unique:true,
          required:true,
          date:{
              type:String,
              unique:true,
              required:true,
          },
          meal:{
              type:Array,
              meals:{
              type:Object,
              required:true,    
              mealId:{
                  type:String,
                  required:true,
              },
              gram:{
                  type:String,
                  required:true,
              }
            }
          }

      }
  }

 

,{timestamps: true});
```

And this is my query for pushing the meals object in the meal array if the date matches

This query runs fine on Mongoshell but not on Mongoose I am getting the following error

```
  const ok = await intakeFoodSchema.updateOne({email:emaill},{$push:{"dateNo.$[el].meal":{mealId:mealid,gram:'4'}}},{arrayFilters:[{"el.date":datess}]})
```

Following is the Error

```
/media/piyush/New Volume/FitBit/Backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/update/castArrayFilters.js:71
        throw new Error(`Could not find path "${filterPath}" in schema`);
              ^

Error: Could not find path "dateNo.0.date" in schema
    at _castArrayFilters (/media/piyush/New Volume/FitBit/Backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/update/castArrayFilters.js:71:15)
    at castArrayFilters (/media/piyush/New Volume/FitBit/Backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/update/castArrayFilters.js:25:3)
    at _castArrayFilters (/media/piyush/New Volume/FitBit/Backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2107:5)
    at model.Query._updateThunk (/media/piyush/New Volume/FitBit/Backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3955:3)
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (/media/piyush/New Volume/FitBit/Backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4079:23)
    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _updateOne] (/media/piyush/New Volume/FitBit/Backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/query/wrapThunk.js:27:8)
    at /media/piyush/New Volume/FitBit/Backend/node_modules/kareem/index.js:279:20
    at _next (/media/piyush/New Volume/FitBit/Backend/node_modules/kareem/index.js:103:16)
    at /media/piyush/New Volume/FitBit/Backend/node_modules/kareem/index.js:508:38
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

If query works fine on terminal then why error persist!!
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Have same error 'Could not find path in schema' with array filters on 6+ Mongoose version.
Jumped back to 5+ Mongoose version (5.13.14), and error dissapear.

I think it's because of changes in 6+ version. Take a look [mirgating from 5v to 6v](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html).

Comment: in 6 it also works

Answer (score -1):

Only for updating the **"mongoose": "6.9.1"**